# Is there any way to shorten up this Facebook API call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook

Right now I am working on an AJAX call that grabs a random photo that a Facebook user is tagged in and then grabs the large source for it. Is there any way to speed this up or at least distill the call into one query?

```
var query1 = encodeURI("SELECT pid,xcoord,ycoord FROM photo_tag WHERE subject={{mystery.uid}} order by rand() LIMIT 1");    
var query2 = encodeURI("SELECT src_big FROM photo WHERE pid=");

function get_pic() {
        var l = $.get("https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q="+query1, 
                {access_token: "{{token}}"},
                function(data1) {
                        $.get("https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q="+query2+data1.data[0].pid, 
                        {access_token: "{{token}}"},
                        function(data2) {
                                $("#mystery_img").html('<center><img src="'+data2.data[0].src_big+'"></center>');
                                var top = $("#mystery_img img").offset().top + Math.floor(data1.data[0].ycoord);
                                var left = $("#mystery_img img").offset().left + Math.floor(data1.data[0].xcoord);
                                var img = $(document.createElement('img')).attr({src: "/static/images/curved_arrow.gif"})
                                    .css('position', 'absolute')
                                    .css('top', top)
                                    .css('left', left);
                                    $("#mystery_img").append(img);
                        }, 
                        "json");
                }, 
                "json");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked with Facebook's API using queries like this, but I know SQL inside and out, and this screams INNER JOIN to me.

```
var joinedQuery = "SELECT Photo_Tag.pid,Photo_Tag.xcoord,Photo_Tag.ycoord,Photo.src_big FROM photo_tag AS Photo_Tag INNER JOIN photo AS Photo ON Photo_Tag.pid = Photo.pid WHERE Photo_Tag.subject = {{mystery.uid}} ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;";
```

Also, the use of `ORDER BY RAND()` is going to be inherently slow (especially with a system as large as Facebooks), so might I recommend something more like this:

```
var joinedQuery = "SELECT Photo_Tag.pid,Photo_Tag.xcoord,Photo_Tag.ycoord,Photo.src_big FROM photo_tag AS Photo_Tag INNER JOIN photo AS Photo ON Photo_Tag.pid = Photo.pid INNER JOIN (SELECT (MAX(pid) * RAND()) AS pid FROM photo_tag WHERE Photo_Tag.subject = {{mystery.uid}}) AS MaxId ON Photo_Tag.pid = MaxId.pid WHERE Photo_Tag.subject =  {{mystery.uid}} ORDER BY Photo_Tag.pid ASC LIMIT 1";
```

Written to be more readable, that query is:

```
SELECT Photo_Tag.pid
    ,Photo_Tag.xcoord
    ,Photo_Tag.ycoord
    ,Photo.src_big
FROM photo_tag AS Photo_Tag
INNER JOIN photo AS Photo ON Photo_Tag.pid = Photo.pid
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT (MAX(pid) * RAND()) AS pid 
    FROM photo_tag
    WHERE Photo_Tag.subject = {{mystery.uid}}
) AS MaxId ON Photo_Tag.pid = MaxId.pid
WHERE Photo_Tag.subject = {{mystery.uid}}
ORDER BY Photo_Tag.pid ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Using `ORDER BY RAND()` requires querying every row to build a new "randomness" ID, creating and populating a temporary table with this newly randomized result set, and then querying from that table to bring back your row. For large datasets, this can be very slow.

By instead `JOIN`ing the table back onto itself with random pids generated, then `ORDER`ing and `LIMIT`ing that dataset, it can result in a much faster query. [This article explains in (enormous) detail what I mean](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/), but also shows that a query such as the one above will be faster with a table holding as little as 100 rows, and will be no slower than the original query in any case.

Even if you don't get rid of `ORDER BY RAND()`, your reduction to a single query should speed up your call.